# How can I create multiple functions with variable in name?

Tags: php, html, function, loops

I have this function:

```
function display_cell_1_url() {
    <input type="text" name="cell_1_url" id="cell_1_url" value="<?php echo get_option('cell_1_url');" />
}
```

How can I declare this function 10 times and  replace `_1_`  in function name and function body?

Comment: this is pseudo code. If it isn't, then that's *already* failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, do not try to have 10 functions! That is not how programming works.

Instead what you should do is have **one** function that does the same thing **10 times**. That's why we have this incredible thing called loops. You can use them like so:

```
function display_cell_url($numOfCell) {

    for($i = 1; $i <= $numOfCell; $i++) {
         echo '<input type="text" name="cell_'.$i.'_url" id="cell_'.$i.'_url" value="'.get_option('cell_'.$i.'_url').'" />';
    }
}

// Use this function like this

display_cell_url(10);
```

This is fairly elementary stuff. If you are new to PHP you should go through some course about the basics of the language.

Code Academy has a great ***free*** PHP course: [HERE](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/php)

Comment: Ok, but how to call 'display_cell_url($i)' from another loop?

Comment: @AlexIschenko If this function is nested then bring it into the same block level `{ .. }` than the loop you're trying to call it from.

Comment: SOLVED Thanks a lot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487549/how-can-i-create-number-of-functions-in-loop/44488257#44488257

Comment: @AlexIschenko Sure, no problem. Don't forget to validate my answer as the selected one if it helped.