# How can i create number of functions in loop

Tags: php

This is my first loop:

```
function cell_fields() {
global $cellcount;
    for($i = 1; $i <= $cellcount; $i++) {
        // add_settings_field( $id, $title, $callback, $page, $section, $args )
        add_settings_field("cell_{$i}_url", "Url", "display_cell_{$i}_url", "options_cell_{$i}", "home_tile_{$i}", array( "class" => "tile_{$i}_field" ));
        register_setting("home_tile_{$i}", "cell_{$i}_url");
        add_settings_section("home_tile_{$i}", "", null, "options_cell_{$i}");
    }
}
add_action("admin_init", "cell_fields");
```

in this loop i call `display_cell_{$i}_url` and i have a `display_cell_1_url` and `display_cell_2_url` ...
I want to create loop from `display_cell_($i)_url` functions instead of 10 separate functions

Comment: you asked this same question twice already; besides this one which now makes three.

Comment: Sounds like an "*X-Y problem*" to me, why do your need this?

Comment: Ok, i create a lop that creates 10 functions, how can i call it from another loop? 'display_cell_url($i);'

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED 
The last parameter takes my arguments and passes them to the callback function.

```
add_settings_field("cell_{$i}_url", "Url ячейки 1", "display_cell_url", "options_cell_{$i}", "home_tile_{$i}", $i);
```

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21256/how-to-pass-arguments-from-add-settings-field-to-the-callback-function

Comment: Thanks to FrenchMajesty